# É possível usar ASYNC AWAIT recebendo retorno de uma PROMISE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async, promises, async-await

Gostaria de saber se é possível receber o retorno de uma promise usando async await?

Criei uma promise onde eu faço a leitura de um arquivo e retorno a string desse arquivo, para receber essa variável, na minha outra funcao eu criei uma função ASYNC await, mas aparentemente ele nao esta esperando essa acao ser executada para dar o console.log() e isso faz com que minha variável venha undefined, segue o codigo.

**APP.JS**

```
const ManagerFile = require('./ManagerFile');

var managerFile = new ManagerFile();

async function readFile() {

    var result = await managerFile.Read('./users.csv');

    console.log(result)

}

readFile();
```

**ManagerFile.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

class ManagerFile {

    constructor() {

        this.readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

    }

    Read(pathFile) {

        this.readFile(pathFile, { encoding: 'utf-8' }).then((data, err)=>{

            return data;

        });

    }

}

module.exports = ManagerFile;
```

**Problema**

console.log(result) - **UNDEFINED**

Comment: No método `.Read()`, falta um `return` antes do `this.readFile`.

Comment: Infelizmente ainda me retorna undefined

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você precisa retornar de fato a `Promise`. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
const returnAPromise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("ASYNC DATA");
    },1000);
  });
};

const getPromise = async () => {
  console.log(`Calling returnAPromise...`);
  const result = await returnAPromise();
  console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
};

getPromise();
```